# How do i trigger an onPress event on a screen render in react native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

Basically what i'm trying to do is to trigger the onpress event whenever i get on this screen, i know how to do this on a non-hooks project, but i never encountered this case on hooks.

i got a calendar component that uses a onSelectedDate() to trigger something whenever you select a day in the calendar, what i need to do is to click on a specific day whenever i go to this screen, so that way it gets selected

do i need to use ref? or props? i don't know, need a example if possible

Comment: Add the accompanied code for more clarity.

Comment: I got your problem and found the solution too, if you can post your code I can give you that solution from your code.

Comment: Please add your solution for non-hooks component, so we can suggest hooks solution

Comment: Do you want to pass that onSelectedDate() functionality to another page and trigger it once its open ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to call the function for the onPress handler from a useEffect hook. You may want to include logic inside of the useEffect so that it only calls it if your state indicates one has not already been selected. Don't forget to include any dependent variables in the array for the second param to avoid unexpected behavior.

Comment: an example will be super useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more like componentDidMount, that is, code that’ll run one time after the initial render, after the component is mounted, you can call `useEffect` like this:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // code to run after render goes here
  }, []); // <-- empty array means 'run once'

  return (
    <div>whatever</div>
  );
}
```